# Write ArrayBuffer to file in scala

Tags: scala, file-io

I want to write multiple `ArrayBuffer`s to file one after the other in append mode in Scala and then I should be able to read the last `ArrayBuffer` from the file and delete it from the file and save the file with the remaining `ArrayBuffer`.

I cant think of any good solution for this. How should I do this?

Comment: Do I get it right that if you have 2 instances of `ArrayBuffer`, you would like to save to file only 1?